# How to convert a matrix consisting entirely of 1's?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I want to make a generalized route done as in the game(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ie4Z2odRjU). The goal is to obtain a possible(not necessarily optimal) sequence making a given 4x3 matrix consisting entirely of 1s.

Rules: you have buttons surrounding the matrix. Each time you press a button, the relative row/column/diagonal switches 0s to 1s (and vice-versa). Assume that only solvable matrices are given. For example (grey is 0):

```
m=matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1), nr=4)
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

[image]
[image]

The matrix is converted by pressing buttons 8,9,7,6,6,5,4,1 to a matrix consisting only of 1. So the desired result is c(8,9,7,6,6,5,4,1)

I guess that the two cores are to express the algorithm converting 0 and 1 each other(possibly together with recursion? I don't know.), and to express operations(in this case, there are 10 operations because the input matrix is 4 by 3) anyhow, which seem to me beyond my ability.

Comment: I guess you posted a similar question before.

Comment: I resigned myself to solving 4X3 matrices case, and if I cannot even solve this special case, I will give up.

Comment: Just wondering why you need to click twice on button 6.

Comment: the example is not optimal solution, so any possible route is sufficient.

Comment: of course, I omitted tried codes which I used. and I have spent several days only for this problem, and so I have almost no will and am about to give up.

Comment: There are 1024 possible switch combinations. You can try them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
f <- list(`1` = function(x) {diag(x) <- !diag(x); x},
          `2` = function(x) {x[1,] <- !x[1,]; x},
          `3` = function(x) {x[2,] <- !x[2,]; x},
          `4` = function(x) {x[3,] <- !x[3,]; x},
          `5` = function(x) {x[4,] <- !x[4,]; x},
          `6` = function(x) {x[4,1] <- !x[4,1]; x[3,2] <- !x[3,2]; x[2,3] <- !x[2,3]; x},
          `7` = function(x) {x[,1] <- !x[,1]; x},
          `8` = function(x) {x[,2] <- !x[,2]; x},
          `9` = function(x) {x[,3] <- !x[,3]; x},
          `10` = function(x) {diag(x[-1,]) <- !diag(x[-1,]); x})

exef <- function(mat, action_vector) {
  require("magrittr")
  paste0("mat %>% f$`", paste(action_vector, collapse = "`(.) %>% f$`"), "`(.)") %>%
    parse(text = .) %>% eval
}

all_possible_actions_list <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  actions <- combn(1:10, i)
  unname( split(t(actions), 1:ncol(actions)) )
  }) %>% unlist(recursive = F)

msolution <- function(m) {
  for (k in 1:length(all_possible_actions_list)) {
    if (sum(exef(m, all_possible_actions_list[[k]])) == 12) break
  }
  all_possible_actions_list[[k]]
}

msolution(m)
# 1 2 3
```